# Join users and usermeta tables - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to select columns from `users` and `usermeta` tables.

This is my query:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID FROM {$wpdb->users} 
    WHERE {$wpdb->users}.user_registered <= '%s' 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='custom_status' 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value=0
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID= {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id", $before);
```

, but it doesn't select nothing. I know that I have one user with this `meta_value` and  `user_registered` less than the current date time (`$before`).

This is what `$before` is like: `2019-07-06 19:03:55`

Comment: Lose the single quotes in `'%s'` (should be just `%s`). Also, I believe your `INNER JOIN` should be placed before the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You can place it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're wrapping the `%s` placeholder in single quotes. That's not needed because WordPress will replace all instances of `%s` with a proper string containing the value you passed to the `prepare()` method.

So, taking that into consideration, your code becomes:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID FROM {$wpdb->users} 
    WHERE {$wpdb->users}.user_registered <= %s 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='custom_status' 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value=0
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID= {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id", $before);
```

Additionally, the `INNER JOIN ...` part of your query has to be placed before your `WHERE` clause or else MySQL will throw an invalid syntax error:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID FROM {$wpdb->users} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID= {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id
    WHERE {$wpdb->users}.user_registered <= %s 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key='custom_status' 
    AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value=0", $before);
```